# I want to call the element inside a tuple of tuples for my function

Tags: python

I want to get True when one of the lines of a tictactoe game is full:

```
teste5=('O','X','X',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ')
teste6=('X','X','X',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ')

def vencedor_linha(t):
    tl1=(t[0],t[1],t[2])
    tl2=(t[3],t[4],t[5])
    tl3=(t[6],t[7],t[8])
    tl=(tl1,tl2,tl3)
    if tl[0:][0:]=='X':
        return True
    elif tl[0:][0:]=='O':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

so `vencedor_linha(teste5)` -> `True` and
   `vencedor_linha(teste6)` -> `False`

Problem is: it gives me `vencedor_linha(teste5)` -> `False`, because I can't get the `if`'s to work correctly.

PS. I can't use lists so don't bother telling me to. :p

Comment: `tl[0:][0:]` doesn't represent what you probably await.  `tl[0:][0:][0:][0:]` is also possible and returns the original `tl`.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that 3 different values are equal to something, you need to use all() or 3 different == conditions; checking if a slice is equal to one value doesn't make any sense.

You want something like:

```
def vencedor_linha(t):
    tl1=(t[0],t[1],t[2])
    tl2=(t[3],t[4],t[5])
    tl3=(t[6],t[7],t[8])
    tl=(tl1,tl2,tl3)
    for row in tl:
        if all(x == 'X' for x in row) or all(x == 'O' for x in row):
            return True
    return False
```

(This checks all 3 rows; it's unclear to me whether your original code is only trying to check the first row.)

Comment: ty, wooble. problem is i cant use all and row.

Comment: @mr e: its a freshman year project, cant use lists yet on this one

Comment: Well, you can unroll the loop and `all()` to 6 `if` statements, if that's what your professor really wants. If it's homework, I'm not going to write that code for you.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner that uses itertools like pretty much everything that does something clever with iterables:

```
from itertools import groupby
def vencedor_linha(t):
    return any(reduce(lambda x,y:x if x==y and x in ['X','Y'] else False,
        (r[1] for r in row[1])) for row in groupby(enumerate(t),lambda (i,v):i/3))
```

Basically:
enumerate(t) returns an iterator where each element is of the form (index of element in t, element in t)

groupby(iterable, keyfunction) returns an iterator where each element is of the form (value, iterator over the elements of iterable for which keyfunction applied to that element returns value)

reduce(function,iterable): Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value. For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5). (from the python docs)

any(iterable) returns True if any of the elements of the iterable evaluate to True, False otherwise.

So we break your tuple into rows with groupby, calculate if each row is homogeneous and only contains 'X' or 'Y' with reduce, and return True if that is True for any of those rows.